# Adding a jQuery modal dialog to the admin area

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, admin

I am writing a plugin for a customer and I need to use lightbox/thickbox/fancybox/etc in my admin piece. No matter what jquery plugin I use, and I'm using wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script, nothing seems to work. No errors or anything. I click a link to open a hidden DIV, and nothing happens.

Anyone have an alternative or a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this could help you, I used this to manage a image field from a meta-box in the post admin page :

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'ImageOnSlider_scripts' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'ImageOnSlider_scripts' );


function ImageOnSlider_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_register_script('my-upload', WP_THEME_URL.'/js/name_of_script.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
 wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
 wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
 }
```

and the JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#input-ImageOnSlider').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#input-ImageOnSlider').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}   

});
```

(name the buttons or link accordingly to the js, or modify js)

Comment: You can also use `add_thickbox()` for easier access to the thickbox.js stuff on admin.

Comment: That was really helpfull for me ;) :) Thanks a lot